# CardView elevation not showing in lollipop and higher versions

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-cardview, elevation

I was using cardview, but the problem is elevation not showing in lollipop and higher versions. please suggest me.Here is my code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/verify_card"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" should have done the magic.. Just as an option try harware accelerated in application tag in manifest and check.

Comment: Try to remove: card_view:cardElevation="2sp" or change it to "2dp". Cardview has an default elevation already... you don't need to set it...

Comment: george-thomas: I tried that tag but no use

Answer (score 81, accepted):

this worked for me.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

total code is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/card_griditem"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">`
```

Comment: actually, u just need add layout_margin on carview. and dont set it to 0, cuz it prevent u from showing the shadow of cardview

Comment: @Uma Achanta can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066346/cardview-gridlayout-with-recyclerview-is-not-fit-for-all-screen-sizes-in-andro

Comment: Actually `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` fixed my problem, thanks

Comment: I used android:elevation="4dp" instead of card_view:cardElevation="4dp" (or app:cardElevation="4dp)

Comment: Works for me after adding card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` as **true** in Manifest.
By setting it to false your application will not able to use GPU and can't make some 2D designs.